# How to declare a new environment similar to abstract in a report?

Tags: errors, environments, report

Similar questions have been asked, but none have answered my particular problem.

I am trying to declare in a report a new environment which would be similar to the `abstract` environment. I have looked at the code in `report.cls` and found the definition for the `abstract` environment:

```
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
```

In my document I have declared the `test` environment in the same fashion, and used it as I would use `abstract`:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\newcommand\testname{Test}

\newenvironment{test}{%
    \small
    \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \testname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation}
    {\endquotation}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
Test
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following error:

```
./test.tex:15: Undefined control sequence. [\begin{test}]
./test.tex:15: Missing number, treated as zero. [\begin{test}]
If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,:15: Illegal unit of measure . [\begin{test}]
```

I understand the problem comes from the `\z@` but I understand neither why nor how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the definition involves the `@` character (with category code `12`), you need to enclose it between `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` to change its category code to `11` during the definition, and back to `12` after the definition:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\newcommand\testname{Test}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{test}{%
    \small
    \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \testname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation}
    {\endquotation}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
Test
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

If insetad of `\z@` you use `0pt`, you don't need `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\newcommand\testname{Test}

\newenvironment{test}{%
    \small
    \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \testname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{0pt}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation}
    {\endquotation}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
Test
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

However, a simpler approach would be to say:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\newcommand\testname{Test}
\newenvironment{test}
  {\renewcommand\abstractname{\testname}\begin{abstract}}
  {\end{abstract}}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
Test
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first code sample resolves the compilation error, and the last code sample answers my initial question. Could you please nonetheless explain why when using `\makeatletter` (or `0pt`) the layout of the defined `test` environment is actually not the same as the `abstract` environment (it is not vertically centred on the page)?

Comment: @sirdharma that's because you are not using the `\null\vfil` and `\vfil\null` commands of the original definition; if you want your environment to behave exactly as the original one (excepting the name), the simpler option is to do something like my last example shows.

Comment: I have already applied your last example and it solves my problem. I would just like to understand where do the `\null\vfil` and `\vfil\null` commands come from in that case? They only seem to be used when the abstract is within the title page if you look at the code I extracted from `report.cls`.

Comment: @sirdharma they are used if the boolean switch `\if@titlepage` is true, and in `report.cls` you find `\@titlepagetrue` so, by default, the boolean switch is true and the first definition applies.